# Export png of UserControl in Background Thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to export in Png a WPF UserControl that I made in a background Thread.

The rendering works great in the UI thread, but I can't run my spinner for user waiting correctly because the two controls run in the UI thread.

When I run my code in the backgroung thread I have the following exception :

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it'

I use the following code to create the thread :

```
 List<Byte[]> images = null;
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            HorizontalViewDesigner horizontalViewDesigner = new HorizontalViewDesigner(true);
            horizontalViewDesigner.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<ICanvasSelection>(elements);
            horizontalViewDesigner.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
            horizontalViewDesigner.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(10_000, 10_000)));
            Size size = new Size(1024d, 1024d);
            images = horizontalViewDesigner.GetImages(size);
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
        thread = null;
        return (images);
```

The exception occurs in the GetImages method on the call of

```
userControl.UpdateLayout();
```

It's seems that this method update Dependency Properties from binding.

Any solution ?
Thanks

Comment: You can't access or modify UI elements from the background thread *in any operating system*. You can't fool the OS either. Exporting means writing an image to a file, not modifying the UI. Manipulating and saving images doesn't require visual components or modifying the UI. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: `I can't run my spinner for user waiting correctly because the two controls run in the UI thread.` why would that be a problem? What spinner?

Comment: Is use  WriteableBitmap to export my control to Images.

If I render my control in the UI Thread, the UI is freezing,and I can't have a loading spinner rotating correctly.
My control contains a lot of items that are databound and lot of DataTemplate / Dependency Properties.

Comment: Then that's what you need to fix. Desktop UIs manage this for 30 years without having to modify the UI from another thread. Do the heavy work on the background thread and get back to the UI thread to update the UI. That's *very* easy nowadays with eg `await Task.Run(()=>SomeHeavyJob());` and the Progress class. `Task.Run` starts a job in a background thread and `await` awaits for it to complete without blocking the UI thread. Once that completes, `await` returns execution to the UI thread